# Semantic Issue on setDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

There is a Semantic Issue with my code. I have a UIWebView and I added an error message so if there's no internet connection, an error pops up.

This is the coding for my UIWebView in my .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *fullURL = @"http://example.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[website setDelegate:self];
[website loadRequest:requestObj]; }
```

The error is on this code

```
[website setDelegate:self];
```

It says it's a Semantic Issue and the error is Sending FirstViewController *const_strong to parameter of incompatible type id

Here is the code for the error message if there is no internet connection

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"error connecting to the internet" delegate:self
cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show]; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that FirstViewController implements  protocol. Something like:

```
@interface FirstViewController ()  <UIWebViewDelegate>
@end
```

The compiler is currently warning you that you're setting a delegate which isn't specifying that it implements the required protocol so no compile check is being performed.

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller should specify that it conforms to [`UIWebViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) by adding "`<UIWebViewDelegate>`" to the end of the `@interface` line, either in the main `@interface` declaration in the `.h`:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Or to the private class extension (if you have one) in the `.m` file:

```
@interface MyViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

See [Conforming to Protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW3) in the *Programming with Objective-C* guide.